# Error When Trying to Run Angular: Unable to move the cache: Access is denied

Tags: angular, google-chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYYLw.png)I have seen this error posted and have tried the solutions offered but nothing seems to work.
Here are the details:
Installed NodeJs – version 18.7.0.
Installed Angluar – the most current version (at this time) 17 – the install was global and created the directory structure with no errors generated.
NPM version: 9.6.7

I am doing all this on a work computer, but I do have admin rights, which I needed to access the C:\ drive to do the Angular install and to try and create a new Angular project. The error below occurs no matter what directory I’m in. In the below screen shot, I’m just trying to check the version.
I’ve noticed from posts around the web that it was happening with Selenium and React – so I’m thinking this may not just be an Angular issue. SOS!!

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev9CR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Command Prompt and select "Run as administrator."

and then run this command **npm cache clean --force**.